# jQuery $.each loop not working properly

Tags: jquery, json, each

When I'm looping through the loop I'm trying to match if array contain a value that user inputs, if yees then message country exist. But this doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
<input type="text"  id="topics" >
<a id="submit-button" href="#">button</a>

$('#submit-button').click(function(){

    var isCountry = $("#topics").val();

    $.each(topics, function(i, item) {
        if(isCountry == topics[i].value){

             alert("country exists");
        }else{
            alert("country doesn't exists");
        }
        });

});
```

full code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/4XHPY/

thank you guys

Comment: What exactly "does not work"? What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: For example if User types "Algeria", it should alert "country exists" and if user types some nonsense "erenqetntnrt" this should alert "country doesn't exists".

Comment: Like that: http://jsfiddle.net/4XHPY/4/

Comment: It does, but only after alerting *"country doesn't exist"* twice. Why? Because `Afghanistan !== Algeria` and `Albania !== Algeria`  and both times you are executing `alert("country doesn't exists")`. Only execute `alert("country doesn't exists")` when you have tested all elements in the array and haven't found a match (as improvement, you should use an object instead of an array to valid looping completely).

Comment: @roasted thanks, that works, simple and easy :)

Comment: @Marcel see jsfiddle in my answer, really better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use that, using lower case too which seems more appropriate:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4XHPY/11/)

```
  $('#submit-button').click(function () {

        var isCountry = $("#topics").val(),
            exists = false;

        $.each(topics, function (i, item) {
            if (isCountry.toLowerCase() == topics[i].value.toLowerCase()) {

                exists = true;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (exists) alert("country exists");
        else alert("country doesn't exists");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working. It just loops over your array (which is stored in topics variable) and alerts a message **on every step** if the entered value is equal to i-th value. So if you enter Algeria then on the third iteration you will see a message "country exists", on all other iterations you will see "country doesn't exists".

Answer (score 2):

In your code each loop is iterated till the length of topics object and that's why giving alert for that much number of times.
Instead of that, use following script:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(){

    var isCountry = $("#topics").val();
     var filtered = $(topics).filter(function(){
        return this.value == isCountry;
    });
    if(filtered.length == 0){
         alert("country doesn't exists");
    }else{
         alert("country exists");
    }

});
```

Here is the working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4XHPY/12/

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in the fiddle as per your requirements.

It is displaying alert message 'country exists' if the input value is in the array. But since your are looping alert message for each index of the 'topics' array, it is also showing 'country does't exist' alert along with 'country exists' alert message.